# What is the integral of a cumulative distribution function?

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions

I cannot find what is the integral of a cumulative distribution function

$$\int G(\xi)d\xi$$

I think it should be simple, but I have no idea where else to look for it.

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: Not really, my calculus is extremely rusty. Do you know how could it be used on it? I think I would need to transform the $G(\xi)$ in something else

Comment: Integral over what domain? If it's over $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, it should diverge, since $G(\xi)\rightarrow 1$ as $\xi\rightarrow +\infty$. Or did you just mean the indefinite integral?

Comment: @JohnBarber, in fact, it is originally over $0$ to $q$, where $q$ is a quantity order and $G(\xi)$ is a distribution of a random demand. But I wanted to know the indefinite integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrating by parts $$\int G(x)dx= x G(x)  - \int x \,G'(x)  dx =x G(x)  - \int x \,g(x)  dx $$

where $G'(x)=g(x)$ is the corresponding density function.

In particular, if $g(x)$ is well behaved ($X$ is continuous) then you could write: $$ \int_a^b x \,g(x)  dx=(G(b)-G(a)) E[X_{a,b}]=P(X\in [a, b])\, E[X_{a,b}] $$
where $E[]$ denotes expected value and $ X_{a,b}$ represents the original r.v. $X$ truncated (conditioned) to the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thanks! However, I had $\int xg(x)dx$ at the beginning and I integrated by parts to get the $\int G(x)dx$.
How would be the steps to solve it for a definite case, for example?

Like, let's say $\int_0^a xg(x)dx$

Comment: You cannot say anything more _in general_. It's just an integral, how to solve it will depend on your particular $g()$ or $G()$

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you!

Comment: what is integral of cdf in english?

Answer (score 3):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $X \in \mathcal{F}$ an integrable random variable.

Notice that

$\int_{-\infty}^{x}F_{X}(z)dz=\int_{-\infty}^{x}P(X \le z)dz=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{\Omega}1_{(X(w) \le z)}(w,z)dPdz\overset{\text{Fubini}}{=}\int_{\Omega}\int_{-\infty}^{x}1_{(X(w) \le z)}(w,z)dzdP=E[\int_{-\infty}^{x}1_{(X(w) \le z)}(w,z)dz]$.

Now, $\int_{-\infty}^{x}1_{(X \le z)}dz=\begin{cases}
\int_{X}^{x}dz=x-X &\mbox{if}\quad x \ge X,\\
0 &\mbox{if}\quad x<X.
\end{cases}$

Hence $\int_{-\infty}^{x}1_{(X \le z)}dz=(x-X)^{+}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{x}F_{X}(z)dz=E[(x-X)^{+}]$